# How to go to a 'def' structure directly with integer variables in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, coordinates

So I'm trying to create an "x, y plane", and based on what x and y equal, there should be one command that takes the variables, and then goes to a 'def' structure accordingly. I could use a lot of 'if' structures, but I imagine there's a much simpler method.

This is something of what I was imagining:

```
def start():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    print(">1. Go up")
    print(">2. Go down")
    print(">3. Go left")
    print(">4. Go right")
    direction = input(": ")
    if direction == (1):
        y = y + 1
    if direction == (2):
        y = y - 1
    if direction == (3):
        x = x - 1
    if direction == (4):
        x = x + 1
    coord(x, y)
def coord(0,1):
    print("You went up.")
def coord(0,-1):
    print("You went down.")
def coord(-1,0):
    print("You went left.")
def coord(1,0):
    print("You went right.")
start()
```

Obviously this returns an invalid syntax. I just need a simple solution. Thank you.

Comment: Why not put the messages inside each `if` that you have already defined?

Comment: You may want to read up on Python, and functions in general.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
def start():
    x = 0
    y = 0

    cases = {1:"You went up",
             2:"You went down",
             3:"You went left",
             4: "You wnet right"}

    while True:
        print(">1. Go up")
        print(">2. Go down")
        print(">3. Go left")
        print(">4. Go right")
        direction = input(": ")
        if direction == (1):
            y = y + 1
        if direction == (2):
            y = y - 1
        if direction == (3):
            x = x - 1
        if direction == (4):
            x = x + 1

        print(cases[direction])
```

This way, it will always ask for the user to type a direction and then it will print the message accordingly.

Comment: No. I understand what you're all suggesting. What I'm trying to do is create multiple outcomes, not just four like I showed. I don't want an "if" statement for every possible outcome. I want to be able to go to multiples different areas. Thanks.

Comment: I see. I updated the answer. Maybe a dictionary would solve, but you would still have to populate the dictionary with the options.